# iTextSharp - finding end of page

Tags: itext

Is there any way to find the current page is going to end in iTextSharp. For example,

say there are some 10 records which needs two pages to be written down at the end of the first page i wish to add '(contd on nex page').  IS there a way to do this.  Will finding the end of page be an answer for this or is there a way to find the line number on which writing is done, so that i can make a calculation to decide whether to add a message of my choice and proceed to the next page.

any advise is much appreciated :)

Thanks a zillion

Answer (score 2):

Usually, this is done by defining a footer for the table. When the table breaks automatically, iText will show that footer. Of course: you don't want this footer to show up on the last page (after the final row of the table). That's why there's also a method to skip the last row.

[This example](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter04/HeaderFooter1.cs) shows you how to create a table with headers and footers. [This](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/PdfPTable.cs#l1562) is the link to `SkipLastFooter`.

Note that saying that "finding the line number" would solve your problem is wrong for two reasons:

1. There is no such thing as a line number in a PDF file. You have a MediaBox and you draw content on the canvas defined by the MediaBox using coordinates.
2. There's a way to get the current Y-position on a page *after* adding an object to a document. You can get the Y-position *before* adding a table and *after* adding a table, but not while you're still creating the table.

An alternative solution to the one I suggested above, woult be to use table events.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to find the end of the page, and are not using a table with a footer row that will be printed at the end of each page, you can use the `PdfWriter` object as follows:

```
var remainingPageSpace = pdfWriter.GetVerticalPosition(false) - pdfDocument.BottomMargin;
```

This will give you the remaining space on the page, from which you can determine what you want to do next.

If you are using tabular data however, it is much preferred to use a `PdfPTable` and take advantage of the footer row feature.